# How can I get the shared steps details for a test case using the .NET SDK client?

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

I use the .NET SDK client (version 16.156.0-preview available on NuGet), but I search how I can get the test case steps that contain the shared steps.
The field `parameterizedString` seems to contain all the test steps, but when it contains the shared steps, the XML content is not clear.

Example of the code I use to get all test steps for a test case:

```cs
private void ReadTestCaseSteps(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.TestManagement.TestPlanning.WebApi.TestCase testCase)
{
    foreach (var field in testCase.workItem.WorkItemFields.OfType<JObject>())
    {
        var stepsContent = ((JValue)((JContainer)field.First).First).Value.ToString();

        using (TextReader stepsReader = new StringReader(stepsContent))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(steps));
            var steps = (steps)serializer.Deserialize(stepsReader);
        }
    }
}
```

The class "steps" is an XML description of this sample:

```cs
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class steps
{

    private stepsStep stepField;

    private stepsCompref comprefField;

    private byte idField;

    private byte lastField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public stepsStep step
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stepField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stepField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public stepsCompref compref
    {
        get
        {
            return this.comprefField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.comprefField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte last
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lastField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lastField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsStep
{

    private stepsStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedStringField;

    private object descriptionField;

    private byte idField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("parameterizedString")]
    public stepsStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameterizedStringField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parameterizedStringField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsStepParameterizedString
{

    private bool isformattedField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool isformatted
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isformattedField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isformattedField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsCompref
{

    private stepsComprefStep[] stepField;

    private stepsComprefCompref comprefField;

    private byte idField;

    private ushort refField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("step")]
    public stepsComprefStep[] step
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stepField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stepField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public stepsComprefCompref compref
    {
        get
        {
            return this.comprefField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.comprefField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public ushort @ref
    {
        get
        {
            return this.refField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.refField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsComprefStep
{

    private stepsComprefStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedStringField;

    private object descriptionField;

    private byte idField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("parameterizedString")]
    public stepsComprefStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameterizedStringField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parameterizedStringField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsComprefStepParameterizedString
{

    private bool isformattedField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool isformatted
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isformattedField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isformattedField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsComprefCompref
{

    private stepsComprefComprefStep[] stepField;

    private byte idField;

    private ushort refField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("step")]
    public stepsComprefComprefStep[] step
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stepField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stepField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public ushort @ref
    {
        get
        {
            return this.refField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.refField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsComprefComprefStep
{

    private stepsComprefComprefStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedStringField;

    private object descriptionField;

    private byte idField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("parameterizedString")]
    public stepsComprefComprefStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameterizedStringField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parameterizedStringField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsComprefComprefStepParameterizedString
{

    private bool isformattedField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool isformatted
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isformattedField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isformattedField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The XML that describes the steps with the shared steps can be like this:

```xml
<steps id="0" last="14">
    <step id="2" type="ValidateStep">
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Step 1&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
        <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Result 1&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
        <description/>
    </step>
    <compref id="6" ref="8712">
        <step id="5" type="ActionStep">
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Step 4&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
            <description/>
        </step>
        <step id="7" type="ActionStep">
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Step 5&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
            <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
            <description/>
        </step>
        <compref id="14" ref="8713">
            <step id="10" type="ActionStep">
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Step 8&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <description/>
            </step>
            <step id="11" type="ActionStep">
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Step 9&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <description/>
            </step>
            <step id="12" type="ActionStep">
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;Step 10&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <description/>
            </step>
            <step id="13" type="ActionStep">
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <parameterizedString isformatted="true">&lt;DIV&gt;&lt;P&gt;&lt;BR/&gt;&lt;/P&gt;&lt;/DIV&gt;</parameterizedString>
                <description/>
            </step>
        </compref>
    </compref>
</steps>
```

So I don't understand how I can read and manage the test case steps with the shared steps with the API in order to transform this content as a list of the detailed steps (description, expected result).

Could you please advise me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested and found that share steps are referred by `ref` attribute of `compref`. The value of `ref` attribute is actually the `id` of the shared steps.

The detailed shared steps is not shown within element `compref`, it only has a `ref` id to the share step.
The element `step` which resides under element `compref` is not the shared steps.

[image]

[image]

After you get the value of `ref` which is the id of the shared step. You can call API again to get the detailed steps within a shared step.

```
GetWorkItemAsync(Int32, IEnumerable<String>, Nullable<DateTime>, Nullable<WorkItemExpand>, Object, CancellationToken)
```

As you said, the compref xml content is not clear. You might need to redefine your steps class to deserialize the xml content, and use the ref value to call api again.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I need to read the Shared Step as a work item and read steps from the field "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps".

I have also changed the xml class "steps" in order to managed sub steps :

```
// NOTE: Generated code may require at least .NET Framework 4.5 or .NET Core/Standard 2.0.
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class steps
{
    private stepsStep[] stepField;

    private steps comprefField;

    private int idField;

    private int lastField;

    private int refField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("step")]
    public stepsStep[] step
    {
        get
        {
            return this.stepField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.stepField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("compref")]
    public steps compref
    {
        get
        {
            return this.comprefField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.comprefField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int last
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lastField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lastField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public int @ref
    {
        get
        {
            return this.refField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.refField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsStep
{

    private stepsStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedStringField;

    private object descriptionField;

    private byte idField;

    private string typeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("parameterizedString")]
    public stepsStepParameterizedString[] parameterizedString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.parameterizedStringField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.parameterizedStringField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.descriptionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.descriptionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public byte id
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class stepsStepParameterizedString
{

    private bool isformattedField;

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public bool isformatted
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isformattedField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.isformattedField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The xml content is not really readable ;)
Thanks for your help.